# Command color not working with the name of a color built through macros

Tags: macros, color, expansion, xparse, programming

Consider the following code and especially the command `\nicecolorname` which builds the name of a color following the pattern ["nice"][shade][hue]. In its current name, the command `\color` is unable to take the output of `\nicecolorname`.

**QUESTION**: How to modify the command `\nicecolorname` to make its output compatible with `\color`? If it's not possible how to modify the code in a way that would work?

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{xcolor-material}

\definecolor{nicelightblue}{named}{MaterialIndigo50}
\definecolor{nicemidblue}{named}{MaterialIndigo500}
\definecolor{nicedarkblue}{named}{MaterialIndigo900}
\definecolor{nicelightred}{named}{MaterialRed50}
\definecolor{nicemidred}{named}{MaterialRed500}
\definecolor{nicedarkred}{named}{MaterialRed900}
\definecolor{nicelightgreen}{named}{MaterialRed50}
\definecolor{nicemidgreen}{named}{MaterialRed500}
\definecolor{nicedarkgreen}{named}{MaterialRed900}

\newcommand{\nicecolorhue}{green}
\newcommand{\nicecolorshade}{dark}
\newcommand{\nicecolorhueref}{\nicecolorhue}
\newcommand{\nicecolorshaderef}{\nicecolorshade}

\NewDocumentCommand\nicecolorname{O{mid} m}{nice#1#2}

\begin{document}
{\color{blue}$\bullet$}                                                  % OK
{\color{nicemidred}$\bullet$}                                            % OK
{\color{\nicecolorname[mid]{red}}$\bullet$}                              % ERROR
{\color{\nicecolorname[\nicecolorshade]{\nicecolorhue}}$\bullet$}        % ERROR
{\color{\nicecolorname[\nicecolorshaderef]{\nicecolorhueref}}$\bullet$}  % ERROR
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument needs to *expand* to a color:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
% only needed in old latex \RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{xcolor-material}

\definecolor{nicelightblue}{named}{MaterialIndigo50}
\definecolor{nicemidblue}{named}{MaterialIndigo500}
\definecolor{nicedarkblue}{named}{MaterialIndigo900}
\definecolor{nicelightred}{named}{MaterialRed50}
\definecolor{nicemidred}{named}{MaterialRed500}
\definecolor{nicedarkred}{named}{MaterialRed900}
\definecolor{nicelightgreen}{named}{MaterialRed50}
\definecolor{nicemidgreen}{named}{MaterialRed500}
\definecolor{nicedarkgreen}{named}{MaterialRed900}

\newcommand{\nicecolorhue}{green}
\newcommand{\nicecolorshade}{dark}
\newcommand{\nicecolorhueref}{\nicecolorhue}
\newcommand{\nicecolorshaderef}{\nicecolorshade}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\nicecolorname{O{mid} m}{nice#1#2}

\begin{document}
{\color{blue}$\bullet$}                                                  % OK
{\color{nicemidred}$\bullet$}                                            % OK
{\color{\nicecolorname[mid]{red}}$\bullet$}                              % no ERROR
{\color{\nicecolorname[\nicecolorshade]{\nicecolorhue}}$\bullet$}        % no ERROR
{\color{\nicecolorname[\nicecolorshaderef]{\nicecolorhueref}}$\bullet$}  % no ERROR
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would that work if the code inside the command is more "complicated"? (like with \ifx and such) If not, how to make a more "robust" design? (it's ok if I have to avoid the use of xparse)

Comment: `\ifx` is expandable but if you put non expandable code there such as `\def` it won't work (and is not fixable) personally I wouldn't use this interface, why not define a command  that sets the color (ie includes `\color` in its definition) rather than a command that has to expand to a color? @Vincent

Comment: @Vincent nothing special about color here, same if you have `\newcommand\foo{2} \setcounter{section}{\foo} works`  but  `\newcommand\foo{\def\anything{}2} \setcounter{section}{\foo} error`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  @Vincent  Yes the interface needs to be changed. I would make the `nicecolorname` a factory command to define as well as produce a command for `mycolor` incorporating the `\color`.  Cuts the code to less than half as well.

Comment: @yannisl yes certainly if this is being used directly, the only reason I see to define an expandable command to generate colors is for interfaces where you have no direct access to the color setting eg hyperref `linkcolor=xxx` or tikx color keys for example.